# model.bert() through the slicing error can anyone let me know why is it?

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, bert-language-model, gpt-2

```
with torch.no_grad():
      logits = torch.zeros(len(definitions), dtype=torch.double).to(DEVICE)
      for i, bert_input in list(enumerate(features)):
          logits[i] = model.ranking_linear(
              model.bert(
                  input_ids=torch.tensor(bert_input.input_ids, dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(0).to(DEVICE),
                  attention_mask=torch.tensor(bert_input.input_mask, dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(0).to(DEVICE),
                  token_type_ids=torch.tensor(bert_input.segment_ids, dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(0).to(DEVICE)
              )[1]
          )
      scores = softmax(logits, dim=0)

      preds = (sorted(zip(sense_keys, definitions, scores), key=lambda x: x[-1], reverse=True))
```

**This Error what i get**

> ---
>
> IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
>  in <cell line: 1>()
> 3       for i, bert_input in list(enumerate(features)):
> 4           logits[i] = model.ranking_linear(
> 5               model.bert(
> 6                   input_ids=torch.tensor(bert_input.input_ids, dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(0).to(DEVICE),
> 7                   attention_mask=torch.tensor(bert_input.input_mask, dtype=torch.long).unsqueeze(0).to(DEVICE),
>
> 6 frames
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in embedding(input, weight, padding_idx, max_norm, norm_type, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
> 2208         # remove once script supports set_grad_enabled
> 2209         *no_grad_embedding_renorm*(weight, input, max_norm, norm_type)
> 2210     return torch.embedding(weight, input, padding_idx, scale_grad_by_freq, sparse)
> 2211
> 2212
>
> IndexError: index out of range in self

I want to run this code and i am confuse why is it giving me a index out of range error